# Select with case in postgres function

Tags: postgresql

I have following sql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION convert_reapeted_sections_to_labels_for_sl_export(ids text[])
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
  SELECT string_agg(label, '' ORDER BY idx)
  FROM unnest(ids) WITH ORDINALITY AS id(value, idx)
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      unnest (xpath('//control-rodzaj-wsparcia/item/label/text()', xml))::text AS label,
      unnest (xpath('//control-rodzaj-wsparcia/item/value/text()', xml))::text AS value
    FROM sl_export_newest_definition
  ) AS cte_sl USING (value);
$$;
```

It works for me, but I have over 10 field types like

> (xpath('//control-rodzaj-wsparcia/item/label/text()', xml))

I can create one function like previous posted per field type, but I thinking about using case in this function with field_type paramter passed, something like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION convert_reapeted_sections_to_labels_for_sl_export(ids text[], field_type text)
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$

  SELECT string_agg(label, ' | ' ORDER BY idx)
  FROM unnest(ids) WITH ORDINALITY AS id(value, idx)
  JOIN (
    case when field_type='control-rodzaj-wsparcia' then
        SELECT
            unnest (xpath('//control-rodzaj-wsparcia/item/label/text()', xml))::text AS label,
            unnest (xpath('//control-rodzaj-wsparcia/item/value/text()', xml))::text AS value
    case when field_type='control-rodzaj-wsparcia2' then 
            SELECT
            unnest (xpath('//control-rodzaj-wsparcia2/item/label/text()', xml))::text AS label,
            unnest (xpath('//control-rodzaj-wsparcia2/item/value/text()', xml))::text AS value
    end
        FROM sl_export_newest_definition
  ) AS cte_sl USING (value);
 
$$;
```

But with this function I get 'syntax error near case'.
It is possible to use case inside join in my function? Or I must create one function per one field_type? It will be code duplication :/

Comment: using `xmltable()` might be easier. But without the actual XML content and the expected result this is impossible to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE` is a function to be used in an expression. It is not the equivalent of `if` that you are used to have in procedural languages like Python or C++. Especially you can't use `CASE` to "run" one `SELECT` statement or the other.

In your case however, you don't need multiple cases at all. Just build your path string dynamically like so:

```
xpath('//' || field_type || '/item/label/text()', xml)
```